# SQL line throwing Error 3134 (Insert Into syntax)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've already looked through similar posts, and haven't been able to single out what exactly is causing my error here.  From what I can tell my syntax is correct, and I've included my build code, which runs properly up until executing the SQL line.

```
rs.MoveFirst
If Me.chkBBB = True Then
Do Until rs.EOF
    strBBB = rs!BBB
    strBrktDet1 = Left(strBBB, 2)
    strBrktDet2 = Right(strBBB, 8)
    If strBrktDet1 = "99" Then varBracket = -1
    If strBrktDet1 = "98" Then varBracket = 0
    strBPINo = Nz(DLookup("[BPINo]", "[Caliper Master]", "[BBB] LIKE" & "'*" & strBrktDet2 & "'"), "N/A")
    strCentric = Nz(DLookup("[CentricItemNo]", "[Caliper Master]", "[BBB] LIKE" & "'*" & strBrktDet2 & "'"), "N/A")
    strCardoneNo = Nz(DLookup("[A1CardoneItemNo]", "[Caliper Master]", "[BBB] LIKE" & "'*" & strBrktDet2 & "'"), "N/A")
    If strBPINo = "" Or Null Then strBPINo = "N/A"
    intQty = rs!Need
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblCaliperOrderDetails (OrderNumber, Cardone, BBB, BPI, Centric, WithBracket, QuantityNd) VALUE(" & lngOrderNo & ", '" & strCardoneNo & "', '" & strBBB & "', '" & strBPINo & "', '" & strCentric & "', '" & varBracket & "', " & intQty & ")"
    Debug.Print strSQL
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Immediate window returns

```
INSERT INTO tblCaliperOrderDetails (OrderNumber, Cardone, BBB, BPI, Centric, WithBracket, QuantityNd) VALUE(18190059, 'N/A', '99-00644L-C', 'N/A', '42172', '-1', 208)
```

Order Number, QuantityNd are numeric fields, all others are text fields, WithBracket is a control source for triple-state checkboxes.

From what I can tell, everything is working right, online SQL checkers tell me my syntax is correct, and I've been on this problem a full day, so I figured I'd ask sharper eyes and brighter minds.

Answer (score 5):

the SQL Keyword is "VALUES" not "VALUE"

Comment: Thank you very much!  Can't believe I missed that.  How embarassing.